# Why is hex value in C++ string not having expected value printed

Tags: c++, hex

I've seen other posts about hex in strings but I'm puzzled about something I have in front of me.
I have this code snippet:

```
std::string st = "\xB5\x62";
printf("len is %d\n", st.length());
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < st.size(); ++i) 
{
    printf("as hex = %x\n", st[i]);
    printf("as dec = %d\n", st[i]);
}
```

What's puzzling me is the way xB5 is handled. The output is:

```
len is 2
as hex = ffffffb5
as dec = -75
as hex = 62
as dec = 98
```

For B5 as hex I expect 'B5' instead of 'ffffffb5' and as dec I expect '181' instead of -75. Can anyone tell me what is going on here?
Thanks.

Comment: Whether `char` is signed or unsigned is implementation-dependent. If it is signed, it's largest positive value is 127.

Comment: `%zu` is the correct format to use here: `printf("len is %d\n", st.length());`.

Comment: I'm kind of a recent C/C++ newbe. Thanks molbdnilo for answering what now seems like a dumb question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the C/C++ novice question.

As answered by [molbdnilo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/404970/molbdnilo)

"\xB5" is larger than a signed character at 181.
Changing the code to something like this fixes the problem (casting up to an unsigned char, and then casting that to an int):

```
std::string st = "\xB5\x62";
printf("len is %d\n", st.length());
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < st.size(); ++i) 
{
    printf("as hex = %x\n", static_cast<int>(static_cast<unsigned char>((st[i]));
    printf("as dec = %d\n", static_cast<int>(static_cast<unsigned char>((st[i]));
}
```

Comment: "`\xB5` is larger than a signed character" is nonsense.  It's a character escape sequence, so it produces a character.  However, that character has the MSB set, so when promotions are applied in the `printf` call, sign-extension happens (on your system... a system with a 9-bit or 16-bit char type wouldn't have the MSB set, and a system with unsigned `char` wouldn't perform sign extension).  (`st[i]` is matched to an ellipsis parameter, and that causes promotions).  That also makes it unnecessary to specifically static_cast to `int`.